# Add a number into an array to complete a set of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this array of objects:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "code": "10",
    }, {
        "code": "14",
    }
]
```

i want to add other values to this array to **have 5 elements**. I want the numbers to start at 10 and end at 14. For example if I have an array with these numbers `[10, 14]` I want to add 3 more number to complete the set `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`. If I have an array with `[11, 12, 13]` and then I add two number it will become like this `[10, 11, 12,  13, 14]`.

Once the missing objects have been added to the array, I sort them in ascending order.

```
.sort(({ code: previousID }, { code: currentID }) => previousID - currentID)
```

**My question is how do I add the missing numbers in order to complete the numbers set of 5 elements?**

This is what I tried to do:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  arr = [
    {
      "code": "10",
    }, {
      "code": "14",
    }
  ]

  addProperty(arr, value) {
    const { length } = arr;
    const found = arr.some(el => el.code === value);
    if (!found) arr.push({ code: value });
    return arr;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.arr.length)
    for (var i=this.arr.length; i<5; i++) {
      this.addProperty(this.arr, i);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        { this.arr.sort(({ code: previousID }, { code: currentID }) => previousID - currentID)
          .map((val, index) => {
            return(<p key={index}>{val.code}</p>)
          }
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a range of numbers and map over it to get an array of objects. No need for the extra sort step:

```js
let range = (a, b) => Array.from({length: b - a + 1}, _ => a++)

//

var arr = [
    {
        "code": "10",
    }, {
        "code": "14",
    }
]

var newArr = range(arr[0].code, arr[1].code).map(code => ({code}))

console.log(newArr)
```

To iterate over a predefined range and keep objects that possibly already exist, put them in a `Map` first:

```
let existing = new Map(arr.map(x => [Number(x.code), x]))

let newArr = range(10, 14).map(code => existing.get(code) ?? {code})
```

Comment: thank you!! but if I have an array with 1 or 3 values by default and I want to add the remaining numbers? for example from `[11]` to `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]` or from `[12, 13, 14]` to `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`